# Folder is interpreted as a file

Tags: python, python-2.7, directory, document, shutil

I am trying to copy a word file from an existing folder and copying it to a new output folder. In this output folder, I have again created different folders as per the user id and inside this the word file should be placed for every user. However, while copying this, I am facing an issue as the id folder is interpreted as 
a file. The output file picture is attached here:

[image: the output file picture is attached here]

I am using the `shutil` module for this and the code which I wrote is:

```
id = tup2[i] 
shutil.copy('C:\\Python27\\mydoc.docx', ('C:\\Python27\\Output\\%s') %(id))
```

Answer (score 4):

that's expected. If the destination folder exists, then [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy) appends the basename of your file and copies the file into the destination folder.

> Copies the file src to the **file or directory** dst. src and dst should be strings. **If dst specifies a directory, the file will be copied into dst using the base filename from src**.

If it doesn't, then `copy` assumes that you want to *copy and change the name* (the unix `cp` commands works exactly the same).

A workaround would be to create the directory beforehand/ensure it's here:

```
import os,shutil
output_dir = os.path.join(r'C:\Python27\Output',str(id))
if not os.path.isdir(output_dir):
    os.mkdir(output_dir)
shutil.copy(r'C:\Python27\mydoc.docx', output_dir)
```

(it's also better to use proper path handling functions from `os.path` and raw strings for litteral windows paths)